# Excel or conditional formatting

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

How do I make a cell blank one I enter a date in the cell to it.
Example
Cell J has the number 12 and has a conditional formatting to highlight it green.
But I want it to turn blank and remove color when I put a date in on cell K.

Would I keep doing conditional formatting or would I do a if than .

Help my report is due tomorrow ..

Any help is greatly appreciated- Mel

I haven’t tried much I’m completely lost

Comment: To make it blank you have to use `VBA` coding. You can set conditional format to text color white so that it looks like blank.

Comment: To hide any value using conditional formating set format to `;;;`

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't need the data to actually be gone, just invisible, you can do conditional formatting on J:J [edit: I see chris neilsen has explained how to blank out the text using formatting; thanks chris, I didn't know that trick] In the Conditional Formatting formatting go to the "Number" tab and select "Custom" at the bottom, and in the "Type" field, type `;;;`.

If you need to distinguish between a proper date format and any other cell contents (e.g. between "3/7/23" and "early march"), you can use the formula
`=LEFT(CELL("format",K1),1)="D"`

If you just need to distinguish between blank cells and cells with any value, you can use the simpler formula
`=K1<>""`